# Approximating musical pitch function (the function $2^x$)

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, computational-mathematics, approximation-theory

I have an old digital synthesizer and I would like to understand how its pitch control was implemented. A perfect representation of a given pitch in an equal temperament scale with the concert pitch of $440$ is given by
$$f(x)=2^{x/1200}\cdot440,$$

where different values of $x$ output different pitches and in this case we consider the values $x=300-1200, 310-1200, 320-1200,...,1500-1200$. In musical terms the output is an octave of pitches starting from middle C, in ten cent intervals.

The synthesizer uses $24$ bit arithmetic for representing pitches, and a sampling rate of $88200$ samples per second, this means representing only pitch values of the form $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$ is possible, for integer $y$. After recording, we obtain the following values $y$, and would like to find a function that goes through all of the points.

```
49767, 50052, 50344, 50635, 50927, 51225, 51519, 51820, 52118, 52421, 52725, 53029, 53336, 53645, 53955, 54268, 54584, 54900, 55219, 55538, 55860, 56182, 56510, 56835, 57166, 57497, 57819,
58156, 58490, 58831, 59171, 59514, 59860, 60207, 60556, 60905, 61258, 61613, 61971, 62330, 62691, 63053, 63417, 63785, 64155, 64526, 64900, 65276, 65656, 66036, 66418, 66804, 67181, 67570,
67961, 68356, 68751, 69149, 69550, 69954, 70358, 70765, 71175, 71588, 72004, 72420, 72840, 73262, 73687, 74112, 74541, 74975, 75409, 75847, 76284, 76728, 77171, 77627, 78076, 78532, 78988,
79443, 79905, 80367, 80831, 81299, 81770, 82244, 82721, 83201, 83684, 84170, 84656, 85145, 85637, 86135, 86633, 87137, 87639, 88149, 88659, 89172, 89689, 90220, 90743, 91268, 91797, 92328,
92863, 93401, 93941, 94485, 95035, 95585, 96138, 96693, 97255, 97820, 98385, 98956
```

Contrasting the values of $y$ with the perfect estimates $y_{est}=\text{round}(f(x) \cdot \frac{2^{24}}{88200})$ gives the following plot for $y_{est}-y$

[image]

Trying out the "obvious" polynomial approximations such as min-max polynomial for estimating $2^x$ and deriving a suitable approximation does not appear to work. As can be seen the above error function is very jagged and that is essentially why. I would like to ask for possible ideas on what methods could have been used to compute the output pitch values on the synthesizer?

Comment: I don't understand what is your table nor what is $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$. The waveform doesn't have to be periodic when sampled at $88200$ Hz so everything is possible. Why do you assume the opposite, ie. what is this "synthesizer with 120 pitches per octave" and how do you get its frequencies (and periods). And why do you care ?

Comment: @reuns The formula $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$ gives the possible ouput pitches for integer $y$. Think about a sawtooth waveform in $24$ bits with integer increments. Then $y$ is the increment of the sawtooth waveform of a given pitch. The digital waveform is still periodic, but aliased so with a longer period. I have recorded pitches in 10 cent increments, for estimation purposes. One cent increments are possible. I care because I would like to emulate the pitch handling and while storing a big table is possible, it seems like there should be a simpler algorithm.

Comment: I don't understand what is $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$. The periodic signals it can produce have frequencies $88200/n$ with $n$ integer or at least rational (ie. period of the signal $=n$), but it can also produce non periodic signals. (I mean the perceived frequency)

Comment: @reuns This is not correct. Think of the following loop with some initial value of $z$.


Loop:
$z= (z+y)\%2^{24}$.

$z$ outputs a sawtooth waveform, which is periodic, however it can be aliased and thus not periodic at $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$, producing extra harmonics. It is still approximately a sawtooth of that frequency.

Comment: $f(z) = (z+y)\%2^{24}$ is $2^{24}$ periodic so with 88200 samples/second it has frequency $88200/2^{24}$ Hertz

Comment: @reuns That is only the lowest frequency it can have. But it is still always approximately a sawtooth with a period of $y\cdot \frac{88200}{2^{24}}$, and the $y$ is what we are trying to obtain for the different pitches.

Comment: Ok I see your mistake. If the synthesizer is producing periodic signals (like sawtooth $(z+y) \% T$ with $T\in 1,\ldots,2^{24}$) then $y/2^{24}$ is not an integer, what is an integer is $2^{24}/y$.

Comment: @reuns I was supposed to say frequency not period in the last comment. I do not see what you are trying to say. Neither of the quantities may be an integer, and that does not matter. Digital synthesizers do not care whether the output is perfectly periodic at the desired frequency, all that matters is we get an approximate waveform which may be aliased.

Comment: @reuns A other way to look at it is that we are sampling a continuous sawtooth with the given periodic frequency and say that this is the frequency of the oscillator.